# How can I determine the website visitor's city and use it in a form

Tags: geolocation

I am making a website for a hotel. And the contact/booking form should contain a text field so that the user can write his/her country/city of origin.

I would like to implement a kind of geotracking, geolocalization or something that allow me to get the country/city of origin and use that information in a form's field so that the field's contents will be delivered with the rest of the information via email.

I have tried the code as in this website http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/util/geo/geo.html, whose code I place here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) { var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",mirage:{responsive:0,lazy:0},oracle:"35/0f710f6add20ad3fc449c08c96bdf2",paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/aav=366183412/"},atok:"3ef00aeff8d6c935da4e270822a8471b",zone:"maestrosdelweb.com",rocket:"0",apps:{"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-309831-1","ga_bs":"2"}}}];var a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.async=!0;a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/aav=4114775854/cloudflare.min.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.__CF=window.__CF||{};window.__CF.AJS={"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-309831-1","ga_bs":"2"}};
//]]>
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
<title>Geolocalizacion con HTML5</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
<style type="text/css">img{border:0}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-309831-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

(function(b){(function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)})(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){if(a){var b;if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{if(a=a.target.src){a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);break a}}b=void 0}_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}})})})(window);
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body onload="detectar()">
<h1>Ejemplo de geolocalizacion basado en HTML5</h1>
<div id="mapa">
</div>
<script src="http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="geo.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function detectar(){
if(geo_position_js.init())
{
    document.getElementById('mapa').innerHTML="Leyendo...";
    geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(mostra_ubicacion,function(){document.getElementById('mapa').innerHTML="No se puedo detectar la ubicación"},{enableHighAccuracy:true});
}   else    {
    document.getElementById('mapa').innerHTML="La geolocalización no funciona en este navegador.";
}
}
function mostra_ubicacion(p){
var coords = p.coords.latitude + "," + p.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById('mapa').innerHTML="<p>latitud="+p.coords.latitude.toFixed(2)+" longitud="+p.coords.longitude.toFixed(2) + "</p>"
            +"<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/?q="+coords+"\"><img src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+coords+"&maptype=hybrid&size=400x400&zoom=12&markers=size:mid|"+coords+"&sensor=false\" alt=\"mapa\"/></a>";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nevertheless, this code returns a map with the user's geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude).

Is it there an easy way to determine this and use that information in a form's field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 geolocation API will get you the user's latitude and longitude (assuming they opt in).  If you need to get info such as the city, country, or postal code, you'll need to use a reverse-geocoding web service.  There are plenty of those out there:

- [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)
- [Bing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980817)
- etc

So take your pick... just make sure to look at the terms & conditions and be sure you won't be in violation once the site goes live.

You should be able to find code samples by googling around a bit, it's a fairly common use case.  The steps will be:

1. Get the user's lat/lng with your existing code.
2. Make an AJAX (JSONP) call to request the reverse-geocode (use your Geocode provider to figure out what URL to use.  eg, for Google it is like [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?bounds=34.172684,-118.604794%7C34.236144,-118.500938&sensor=false)).
3. Parse the JSON response to extract the info you need (country, city).

Comment: I love this way but to be honest, I am not that experienced with the implementation of this features. Any code or examples is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo see my update, I'd recommend trying some stuff and come back to SO to ask specific questions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service) talked about a webservice that allows for geolocation based on IP address

You could use this to implement a server-side solution that generates the markup with their location filled in.

Comment: So I can see that this feature is based on a third party service? Is it there a way to do it without third party services dependence?

Comment: Well, the GeoLite answer is an actual database, so you can implement it in whatever language you wish to use it with.  Just mind the creative commons license.

Answer (score 1):

The old fashioned (and still prevalent!) way is to do a reverse lookup of the client IP address :)

Comment: As I mentioned in @dbaseman's answer, I am not that experienced doing this kind of implementation and I knew about reverse lookup of the client IP address but I don't yet know how to get that information and put it inside of a text box in a form. I really appreciate your help and if you know how to do this please let me know. Thank you